# Is there a way to get parent css link rel inside every iframe?

Tags: jquery, css, iframe, parent

I've a page with it's main stylesheet stored in the css folder.
Inside the same page I've multiple iframes (hosted in another folder but same domain) that I want them to use the same CSS as their parent.
Please advise, I'm very new to JS in general.

I've tried the following code and everything works perfect, the only problem is that I've 15 iframes for now and of course to each of them it will add 15 times the code .
I can't use IDs inside the code or else I'll need to setup the script for each of them.

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $("iframe").on("load", function() {
      let head = $("iframe").contents().find("head");
      let css = '<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/stylesheet.css">';
      $(head).append(css);
    });
  </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are referring to the first iFrame, always. Change the code to refer to each iframe like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("iframe").on("load", function() {
      let head = $(this).contents().find("head");
      let css = '<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/stylesheet.css">';
      head.append(css);
    });
  </script>
```